# Return to second fragment from other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have 3 fragments in my MainActivity and I have set the second fragment as the default fragment (when you launch the app, you will see the second fragment).

I want to implement a code similar to OnBackPressed() that when the user presses the back button of phone and he/she is in 1st or 3rd fragment, instead of quiting the app, the application return to the second app.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager2 mPager; 
    private FragmentStateAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private int num_page = 3;
    private CircleIndicator3 mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        mPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, num_page);
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    
        mIndicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        mIndicator.createIndicators(num_page,0);
    
        mPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1000, false);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                if (positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                mIndicator.animatePageSelected(position%num_page);
            }
        });
    
        mPager.setPageTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
                float myOffset = position;
                if (mPager.getOrientation() == ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
                    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(mPager) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
                    } else {
                    }
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
    page.setTranslationY(myOffset);
    page.setTranslationX(-myOffset);
    page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public int mCount;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity fa, int count) {
        super(fa);
        mCount = count;
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        int index = getRealPosition(position);
        if (index == 0) return new FragFirst();
        else if (index == 1) return new FragSecond();
        else return new FragThird();
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2000;
    }

    public int getRealPosition(int position) {
        return position % mCount;
    }
```

FragFirst, FragSecond and FragThird

```
public class FragFirst extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup, container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_1p, container, false);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you `addToBackStack` its transaction when you go to the 1st or the 3rd, then you can back to the 2nd when `onBackPressed`.

```
fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mainContainer, thirdFragment, ThirdFragment.TAG)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Can you just give me some details?

Comment: @Marcus I can't show any more details with you not showing your code. Especially, I need your code about switching from the 2nd fragment to the 1st or the 3rd one.

Comment: Hi, i have put my codes now. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Marcus I posted another Answer based on your updated post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google's official training](http://Slide%20between%20fragments%20using%20ViewPager2), you can define `onBackPressed` in the Activity like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the 2nd page, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 || viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
        // Select the 2nd page.
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    } else {
        // There is no such a page number.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

(* In addition to the above, the official training uses `FragmentActivity` rather than `AppCompatActivity`. I don't know whether it relates this problem or not.)